# How to use unpacked data msgpack-c

Tags: c, deserialization, msgpack

I know how to unpack data but don't know how to use specific data from array or map, Here's the code :

```
#include <msgpack.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  /* msgpack::sbuffer is a simple buffer implementation. */
  msgpack_sbuffer sbuf;
  msgpack_sbuffer_init(&sbuf);

  /* serialize values into the buffer using msgpack_sbuffer_write callback
   * function. */
  msgpack_packer pk;
  msgpack_packer_init(&pk, &sbuf, msgpack_sbuffer_write);

  msgpack_pack_array(&pk, 3);
  msgpack_pack_int(&pk, 1);
  msgpack_pack_true(&pk);
  msgpack_pack_str(&pk, 7);
  msgpack_pack_str_body(&pk, "example", 7);

  msgpack_unpacked result;
  size_t off = 0;
  msgpack_unpack_return ret;
  int i = 0;

  msgpack_unpacked_init(&result);
  ret = msgpack_unpack_next(&result, sbuf.data, sbuf.size, &off);
  while (ret == MSGPACK_UNPACK_SUCCESS) {
    msgpack_object obj = result.data;
    printf("Object on %d:\n", ++i);
    msgpack_object_print(stdout, obj);
    printf("\n");
    ret = msgpack_unpack_next(&result, sbuf.data, sbuf.size, &off);
  }
  msgpack_unpacked_destroy(&result);

  return 0;
}
```

How can I store the first index of the array in a variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

msgpack-c (C version) document is here:
https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_c_overview#object

In your case, the variable `obj`'s type is msgpack_object.

```
typedef struct msgpack_object {
    msgpack_object_type type;
    msgpack_object_union via;
} msgpack_object;
```

`msgpack_object_union` is defined as follows:

```
typedef union {
    bool boolean;
    uint64_t u64;
    int64_t  i64;
#if defined(MSGPACK_USE_LEGACY_NAME_AS_FLOAT)
    double   dec; /* obsolete*/
#endif /* MSGPACK_USE_LEGACY_NAME_AS_FLOAT */
    double   f64;
    msgpack_object_array array;
    msgpack_object_map map;
    msgpack_object_str str;
    msgpack_object_bin bin;
    msgpack_object_ext ext;
} msgpack_object_union;
```

`msgpack_object_array` is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t size;
    struct msgpack_object* ptr;
} msgpack_object_array;
```

`obj.type` is `MSGPACK_OBJECT_ARRAY`.
You can access array elements using the member `via`.
For example, you can access the first index of the array `obj.via.array.ptr[0]`.

When you pack as follows:

```
  msgpack_pack_array(&pk, 3);
  msgpack_pack_int(&pk, 1);
  msgpack_pack_true(&pk);
  msgpack_pack_str(&pk, 7);
  msgpack_pack_str_body(&pk, "example", 7);
```

obj has the following values:

---

- `obj.via.array.size` is `3`.

---

- `obj.via.array.ptr[0].type` is `MSGPACK_OBJECT_POSITIVE_INTEGER`.
- `obj.via.array.ptr[0].via.u64` is `1`.

---

- `obj.via.array.ptr[1].type` is `MSGPACK_OBJECT_BOOLEAN`.
- `obj.via.array.ptr[1].via.bool` is `true`.

---

- `obj.via.array.ptr[2].type` is `MSGPACK_OBJECT_STR`.

  - `obj.via.array.ptr[2].via.str.ptr` is `"example"` (The address of the memory that the first charactor `e` is stored).
  - `obj.via.array.ptr[2].via.str.size` is `7`.

---

> How can I store the first index of the array in a variable ?

So you can do that as follows:

```c
uint64_t store_value = obj.via.array.ptr[0].via.u64;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I notice that when there is two consecutive strings example ["ab", "cd"] obj.via.array.ptr[0].via.str.ptr == "abcd". How to solve this ?

Comment: It seems that \0 termination related issue. You can know the size of the string by obj.via.array.ptr[0].via.str.size.